# Comparative Construction - She can get through more work in an hour than I can get through in a day

Tags: grammar, comparatives

I was reading the Comparative Construction Chapter from The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Pullum and Huddlestone.

There on page 1109, I came across one sentence:

> He is more afraid of her than [she is __ of him].

It is written there that the contrast lies not in the head of the comparative phrase (*afraid*) but in the post head dependents. And that is why *"__ of him"* is an Adjective Phrase with a missing head and missing degree modifier. It is possible to repeat the head in such circumstances. Thus the quoted sentence above can be written as follows -

> He is more afraid of her than [she is __ afraid of him].

But on the same pages a little further down another sentence is illustrated:

> She can get through more work in an hour than [I can get through __ in a day].

If we analyse this sentence like the one above we will see it is the contrast between the amount of *"work in an hour"* vs that of *"work in a day"*.

Then why in the last sentence it is wrong to include *work*?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just superfluous. The item being discussed is work, so it's already understood. Compare: "She can eat more cabbage in an hour than I can [eat] ice cream in a day."

Comment: @Robusto that is understood. Here the counterpart of the comparative complement is distinct. And hence we have to keep "ice cream" there. That is how CaGEL exppains. But in case of my sentence the "work" and "afraid" is same. Difference is the the post head dependents - "of him" vs "of her" and "in an hour" vs "in a day".

Comment: @BillJ but CaGEL says it can be included. On that page itself.

Comment: Yes: it would be better to say 'unnecessary' than 'wrong'.

Comment: @BillJ then is not it strange that in the last sentence in my question, "work" can't be included in comparative complement?

Comment: You’re right. Replacing the ellipsed _work_ with a non-ellipsed something else (eg _play_) is fine, but duplicating _work_ isn’t idiomatic. I don’t think there is an analytic _why_ to this. It has likely become idiomatic through common usage.

Comment: @BillJ did you find anything regarding this?